# read function in c not recognize hex

Tags: c

i have the next problem i wanna exit from the while statement when press de space bar 
but the read function in c not recognize the hex char, the code below.

```
while (c!='0x20')
        {
                if (read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0)        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1); 
// if new data is available on the serial port, print it out
                if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&c,1)>0)
                {
                    printf("\ningresaste %c ",c);
                    write(tty_fd,&c,1);
// if new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port
                }  
        }
```

and so sorry for my english.

Comment: c!=0x20 it should be like this

Comment: 0x20 is decimal 32. Or you could just use `" "`

Comment: Please find out how to turn on warnings in your compiler. Most compilers would warn against `while (c!='0x20')` with a message like
       `"warning: 
      comparison of constant 813183536 with expression of type
      'char' is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
while (c!='0x20') c++;"` . Turn on warnings, and improve your code until they go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 while (c!='0x20')
```

It specifies a multi-character literal based on the characters within the quotes, not their numerical value.

You should either use

```
 while (c!= ' ')   // Because 0x20 is a space
```

or

```
 while (c!= 0x20)  // Hexadecimal integer literal
```

or

```
 while (c!='\x20') // Character literal with hexadecimal value
```

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation of three different ways to specify a character. The cherry on the cake would be explaining what exactly is wrong with the original...

Comment: @user3338446 Note that even though there are many alternatives shown, the best for this case is definitely `c != ' '` so that the reader doesn't have to know that `0x20` is a space.

Comment: @user3338446 you accidentally wrote an "extended character" whose value is 813183536 - in hex this is `0x30783230` which is the ascii values of `0`, `x`, `2`, `0` strung together. In other words - it's like you are looking at the _string_ `0x20` without the terminating `'\0'` character! It is _treated_ as a wide character - but not one that you can expect to compare with a space...

Comment: What exactly does *hex binary value* mean? As far as I know, *hex* means *hexadecimal*, means *in the base of 16*; and *binary* means *in the base of 2*...

Comment: Binary or hex is just a representation of a value, just like decimal is. If you write 0x20 or 32 it's the same value in different bases. Inside the computer there is no hex or binary, there is just the value which you can print in different representations.